# async/await javascript asincrónico

Tags: javascript

```js
const insertNum = ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const numUsuario = Number(window.prompt("Introduce un número (1 - 6):")); 
          // Pide al usuario que introduzca un número
        const aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1); 
          // Elige un número aleatorio del 1 al 6
      
        if (isNaN(numUsuario)) {
          reject(new Error("Tipo de entrada incorrecta")); 
              // Si el usuario introduce un valor que no es un número, 
              // ejecuta reject con un error
        }
      
        if (numUsuario === aleatorio) {
          // Si el número del usuario coincide con el número aleatorio, 
          // devuelve 2 puntos
          resolve({
            puntos: 2,
            aleatorio,
          });
        } else if (numUsuario === aleatorio - 1 || numUsuario === aleatorio + 1) {
          // Si el número del usuario es diferente al número aleatorio por 1, 
          // devuelve 1 punto
          resolve({
            puntos: 1,
            aleatorio,
          });
        } else {
          // Si no, devuelve 0 puntos
          resolve({
            puntos: 0,
            aleatorio,
          });
        }
      });
      
      
      const continuarJuego = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (window.confirm("¿Quieres continuar?")) { 
              // Pregunta si el usuario quiere continuar el juego
              // con un modal de confirmación
            resolve(true);
          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        });
      };
    
    }
      
      const suponer = async () => {
        try {
          const result = await insertNum(); 
            // En lugar del método 'then', podemos obtener el resultado 
            // directamente, poniendo 'await' antes de la promesa
          alert(`Dado: ${result.aleatorio}: obtuviste ${result.puntos} puntos`);
      
          const estaContinuando = await continuarJuego();
      
          if (estaContinuando) {
            suponer();
          } else {
            alert("Terminó el juego");
          }
        } catch (error) { 
            // En lugar del método 'catch', podemos usar la sintaxis 'try/catch'
          alert(error);
        };

    }
    insertNum()
    suponer()
```

En este codigo al ejecutarlo con el respectivo html, aparece el error que indica que la función ejecutarJuego() no está definida, siendo que la veo definida. Además aparece dos veces el alert que pregunta por el número.
Si alguien puede ayudarme a corregir esta situación , quedaré muy agradecido . cambié el orden de algunas funciones , considerando que se trata de javascript asincrónico. El código está ordenado y es bastante legible.Ahora bien la función ejecutarJuego, tiene solamente relve, no sé si puedan funcionar unicamente con ese parámetro o es necesario que también incluya reject.

Comment: Sería bueno que incluyas una pequeña explicación de lo que tu código hace, parece ser un juego, un caso de uso simple vendría genial. Por la parte de que `continuarJuego()` dice que no está definido, es porque lo tienes dentro de `insertNum()`, función que no comparte scope con `suponer()` por esta razón, es correcto que te diga que no es una función definida.

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice @ricardo-dlc, He dejado como respuesta el código corregido explicando los 2 puntos que se le presentan la del scope y la del llamado doble que se hace en el código. Me pareció gracioso, no por burlarme del código sino que son errores que a veces no vemos cuando estamos muy metidos en el código. A veces es bueno darse un break, tomar aire o distraerse de lo que se hace y retomar a revisar lo que se presenta. Eso ayuda muchisimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como aporte a tu respuesta, en realidad creo que debes llevar mucho mirando y seguramente no logras captar lo que te sucede. Te ayudaré con un respiro.

Son 2 cosas que se tuvieron que hacer minimas, pero vitales y son lo siguiente:

1. Haces el llamado de la función `insertNum` 2 veces. Al final de tu código de manera independiente, es decir que solo lo llamas pero ahí muere ese llamado y el segundo llamado es el que ya debes ejecutar realmente y es cuando llamas la función `suponer`, ya que esta hace el llamado a la funcion `insertNum`
2. La función `continuarJuego` ciertamente existe, pero no donde debe. Ya que la has creado en el scope de la función `suponer` mas específico en la promise de esa función. Y donde la necesitas es al mismo nivel que la función `suponer` y `insertNum`.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, comparto el código funcionando con las 2 correcciones mencionadas anteriormente:

```js
const insertNum = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const numUsuario = Number(window.prompt("Introduce un número (1 - 6):"));
    // Pide al usuario que introduzca un número
    const aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    // Elige un número aleatorio del 1 al 6

    if (isNaN(numUsuario)) {
      reject(new Error("Tipo de entrada incorrecta"));
      // Si el usuario introduce un valor que no es un número, 
      // ejecuta reject con un error
    }

    if (numUsuario === aleatorio) {
      // Si el número del usuario coincide con el número aleatorio, 
      // devuelve 2 puntos
      resolve({
        puntos: 2,
        aleatorio,
      });
    } else if (numUsuario === aleatorio - 1 || numUsuario === aleatorio + 1) {
      // Si el número del usuario es diferente al número aleatorio por 1, 
      // devuelve 1 punto
      resolve({
        puntos: 1,
        aleatorio,
      });
    } else {
      // Si no, devuelve 0 puntos
      resolve({
        puntos: 0,
        aleatorio,
      });
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Se saca la funcion de la promesa donde se ha creado y se coloca al mismo nivel de las funciones insertNum y suponer
 */
const continuarJuego = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (window.confirm("¿Quieres continuar?")) {
      // Pregunta si el usuario quiere continuar el juego
      // con un modal de confirmación
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
};

const suponer = async() => {
  try {
    const result = await insertNum();
    // En lugar del método 'then', podemos obtener el resultado 
    // directamente, poniendo 'await' antes de la promesa
    alert(`Dado: ${result.aleatorio}: obtuviste ${result.puntos} puntos`);

    const estaContinuando = await continuarJuego();

    if (estaContinuando) {
      suponer();
    } else {
      alert("Terminó el juego");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // En lugar del método 'catch', podemos usar la sintaxis 'try/catch'
    alert(error);
  };
}
// insertNum() Se comenta esta funcion puesto que no se necesita usar aqui
suponer()
```

Comment: Ok. Me queda muy claro. Gracias por tu ayuda